# Directory Sync AD Connect multiple Domains

Tags: azure-active-directory

I’ve recently been asked to look at a sync issue with Azure AD, however the guy who set it up has left and we have no idea where it’s configured from (AD Connect server) and what it is actually synchronising.

We also want to start synchronising our PP domain to the same AZure AD tenant, is that possible with not knowing what is being synced already and how would I resolve any conflicts, so confused!

Hope someone can help

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, absolutely it is possible to sync multiple domains. the easiest way to to know what is synced is by opening the azure ad connect "synchronization Service" app elevated as administrator. if you click the connectors, tab you will see what domains / forests are configured to sync. I would use the wizard to config more forests / domains.

Here are the supported topologies: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/hybrid/plan-connect-topologies#multiple-forests-single-azure-ad-tenant

Note that there can only be one azure ad connect syncing to a tenant at any given time, you cannot use multiple aad connect servers for that purpose.

Comment: does this mean you have to one ad connect server per domain and they all sync with azure ad at different times?

Comment: no it means you are only allowed to have one azure ad connect server per Azure Tenant. so it means that one azure ad connect server must be able to connect to all the domains that you wish to sync to azure ad.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help. I do have a question about Azure ADDS which I'll be posting later, I'd appreciate if you can take a look. Thanks